# Modify source files on maven build?

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-plugin

Is there some clever established way to modify source files on maven build maybe using a maven plugin?

Comment: A Maven build should avoid to modify files outside `/target` because the builds becomes irreproducible and cannot be tidied up with `mvn clean`. So you usually either have the (normal) handwritten source code or you generate source code (from XML files etc.). What exactly do you want to modify?

Comment: Simlar like this project is doing https://github.com/ertugrulcetin/CommentRemover I guess the answer lies in figuring out how this is implemented.

Comment: I successfully modified source code with roaste https://github.com/forge/roaster . You can write a Maven plugin that copies all the source code to a subfolder of `target`, modifies the files with roaster and adds the directory as source code directory to the Maven build. You would need to make sure, though, that `src/main/java` is _not_ considered as source code directory any more, which can probably be done in the compiler plugin.

Comment: The question is really what you like to achieve?